# Spring AOP - Aspect doesn't intercept anything

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        new Test().test();
    }
}
```

---

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("TEST");
    };
}
```

---

**Aspect.java**

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class Aspect {
    @Around("execution(* Test.*(..))")
    public Object test(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Aspect: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

---

I think that I posted all! Tell me if something is missing.

I placed a breakpoint in the method test of the Aspect, nothing. His default constuctor is called during the Spring initialization so he's correctly initialized when the Context goes up.

I don't know why but the Aspect isn't intercepting anything. I tried different Pointcuts, specifically I need to intercept a custom annotation with some custom exceptions, I simplified the code to post it here.

Anyway even running this code I can't get `System.out.println` that I placed in the `test()` method from the *Aspect.java* class.

The compilation process is just fine. even running the app all is correctly working, except with this.

I'm on IntelliJ IDEA, if that can in some case interfer with the weaving process I don't know.

But maybe the error is more stupid than I think.

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`.

Comment: The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation contains the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` so it is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AOP can only create proxies for Spring components and add aspect interceptors (advices) to them. Your class `Test` is not a `@Component` and I see no configuration creating a Spring bean from it.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the full package in the @Around annotation:

```
@Around("execution(* com.mysite.mypackage.Test.*(..))")
```